# Very Basic question c++) Why is my print answer different from what I wish to get?

Tags: c++

Here is my simple source code:

```
char a, b;
cin >> a >> b;


if (a >= 'A' && a <= 'Z')
{
    a = a + 'a' - 'A';
    cout << a;
}
if (a >= 'a' && a <= 'z')
{
    a = a + 'A' - 'a';
    cout << a;
}
if (b >= 'A' && b <= 'Z')
{
    b = b + 'a' - 'A';
    cout << b;
}
if (b >= 'a' && b <= 'z')
{
    b = b + 'A' - 'a';
    cout << b;
}
return 0;
```

}

I want to change small letters into capitals and vice versa. Small letters works find but somehow capitals don't.

Comment: The first `if` changes `a` to lower case, but the second is always executed and, if `a` is lowercase, converts it to uppercase. The same goes for the third and fourth `if`. ALL letters input are therefore converted to uppercase (uppercase letters converted to lower case, then converted back to uppercase). Try adding adding an `else` before the second `if` in both cases. Also, your tests like `a >= 'A' && a <= 'Z'` and conversions like `a = a + 'a' - 'A'` are not guaranteed for all character sets or locales. Use functions from standard header `<cctype>` like `isupper()` and `toupper()`.

Answer (score 6):

You second `if` statement, for example, has the effect of reversing the first `if` statement.

Writing

```
if (a >= 'A' && a <= 'Z')
{
    a = a + 'a' - 'A';
    cout << a;
}
else if (a >= 'a' && a <= 'z')
```

and so on, is the fix. (Note the `else`.) Apply the same scheme to `b`.

Once you have this working, use the C++ standard library functions `std::islower`, `std::tolower`, `std::iuspper`, and `std::toupper` instead. The code you present is not strictly portable as the standard does not guarantee that the alpha characters are in order.

Comment: How can a word both uppercase and lowercase at the same time?

Comment: @김선달 the first `if` makes it lowercase and the second `if` changes to uppercase again as there is no `else`

Comment: What do you mean by non portable ? Isn't it ASCII std?

Comment: @TruthSeeker: ASCII is indeed *a* standard, but it's by no means the only encoding supported by C++.

Comment: Could you please share the example of a system where this code isn't be portable?

Comment: @TruthSeeker: Certain IBM mainframes.

Comment: @TruthSeeker -- [EBCDIC](http://www.astrodigital.org/digital/ebcdic.html).

Answer (score 3):

The simpler approach would be to do it like this...
Check the value of a if it's upper or lower, then simply convert it accordingly.

```
char a, b;
cin >> a >> b;
if (isupper(a))
{
    a = ::tolower(a);
} else {
    a = ::toupper(a);
}
cout << a;
if (isupper(b))
{
    b = ::tolower(b);
} else {
    b = ::toupper(b)
}
cout << b;
return 0;
```

Edited to simplify code, thanks to Bathsheba

Comment: If you use `isupper` and `islower`, and add some explanation of the method then this would be a good answer: `if (a >= 'A' && a <= 'Z')` is not portable.

Comment: Why ::tolower instead of just tolower?